# How to resolve Connection reset Exception during Spring Batch Job Run?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am encountering `Connection reset exception` during `Spring Batch Job run`. I have been trying to analyze the root cause of this error and provide a solution but not sure what is causing this. Network team says that the servers are running fine there is no connection interruption. The amount of data this job processes is huge sometimes 90K transactions but most of the times 80K - 85K. So sometimes I see no failures for 90K transaction but sometimes I see a lot of `Connection reset` for only 60K transactions.

Please let me know what else should I take into consideration in order to get rid of this.

Stack trace:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:136) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:152) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:270) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:161) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:153) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123) ~[httpcore-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106) ~[httpclient-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
at com.mercuryinsurance.r3.util.RatingRequestProcessor.postRequestToDC(RatingRequestProcessor.java:376) ~[migration.jar:?]
at com.mercuryinsurance.r3.util.MigrationExecutorThread.run(MigrationExecutorThread.java:59) [migration.jar:?]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_66]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_66]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_66]
```

Thanks

Comment: The connection may not be interrupted but if a process takes too long the server may hang up. How long is the connection running for?

Comment: It takes around 1 hour and 45 min to complete around 80K transactions, but in between I see failures. For instance out of 80K 70 transactions fail due to this error.

Comment: Whatever your target system is should have logs explaining why it is closing the connection if there's a bunch of individual failures.

Comment: So this is what it says, I've added the log as part of my question. I only see Connection reset exception for individual transactions.